# No break point hitting in debugging ASP.Net website with IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, debugging, iis

I have setup an asp.net website with local IIS not remote server. Steps I followed to do the same are:

1. Open the project in VS 2008
2. Publish the website to local folder
3. Set up a website in IIS (Windows 10 OS)
4. Point the physical path to my project's Publish folder

So I got my website working under URL : http://localhost/Sample1.
Now I want to debug the IIS website in my VS2008. So

5. Opened my project in VS2008
6. Chose option `Debug >> Attach to Process >> w3wp.exe` to open in the debug mode

I got it attached to the program, but not hitting any break point. I googled the problem and tried pretty much every answer I found , but still the same issue.
I tried:

- chose option `Debug >> Windows >> Modules load symbols from Microsoft symbol server>>`
- Delete all temporary Asp.Net files
- Right click project in Solution Explorer, chose `Properties >> Common Properties >> Statrtup Project >> Multiple startup`, the set Action to Start for my project.

Nothing saved me. I would really appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: Do you get any error message in the output window? Could you visit the URL directly in your browser after you publish it to IIS? Could you visit the debug Modules window to find much more detailed information about which symbols were not loaded. Actually VS 2008 was really an old version, we also don't support this version now. If possible, I suggest you use the higher VS version. You know that it would have much more new features. For example, the VS2017/VS2015 community is free.

Comment: thanks @JackZhai-MSFT. I can visit URL directly in my browser. Actual problem is i cannot connect to the local sql db when its in IIS. So I tried to debug through the local program to find out the exact error line and details. But its not hitting any break point. I checked the debug Modules, the warning symbol near break point asking to load the symbols and I did the same. still no luck. :(

Comment: Could you load the symbols in Debug Modules window manually? Does it have any error or Exception messages in the output window? Please make sure that the app has no compiled Error or Exception during debugging. For example, just enable the Exception under Debug menu  in VS IDE, debug it again.

Comment: Thank you very much @JackZhai-MSFT. You saved me.. Still no luck in break point hit, but I am able to view detailed error messages now. :)

Comment: If it has the Exception, you have to resolve it firstly, maybe it is the real reason why the debug breakpoint was not hit:)

Comment: Do you resolve this issue? Would you please share the latest information about it?

Answer (score 0):

publish with debug mode not release mode,otherwise not hitting your break point!